# Runtime or compile time error for type check in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, categories

Currently in our SDK we allow the user to set key/value information on the user record, this information could only be Date, String or Number. We created a protocol we call it Attribute, we extended (category) NSString and NSDate and confirm it to the protocol. So now in our method that sets these attributes, we ask for a value argument that confirm to the Attribute protocol. This will help us do compile time check, but I wonder if necessary due the dynamic nature of Objective C (I’m a Java developer), is it better to do run time check and return NSError if the value not of type NSString NSDate or NSNumber ?

Comment: A compile-time error is detected in the programming shop.  A run-time error, not necessarily.

Comment: (Or, as I've been known to say:  Let the customers do the testing -- they're such a PITA generally, they might as well do *something* useful.  I don't know what else they're good for!)

Comment: The application could fail gracefully. Just wonder what is the best practice for ObjC developers?

Comment: It's not clear from your description what you're checking in your categories, or how it's doing a compile-time check.  Fundamentally it sounds like you're in effect specifying a class/struct and having the parameters assigned to that, vs, eg, placing the parms in a dictionary.  This does assure that the data types are correct, the parms correctly spelled, etc.  How important this is to you is up to you to judge -- there's always a trade-off between "strictness" and "flexibility" that affects coding costs and bug rates, and not always in a predictable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

A decision is depend on application behavior to wrong data.
It's unnecessary make error if it's wrong data at release, you should check values and converse, for example, int to NSNumber when user typed this data, not after all operations. 
It's your choice, will you strongly lead one to another or check if(error) etc..